# Should a 500 item lookup list be data cached on server?

Tags: jquery, database, caching

I have a column of 500 names <30 characters, that are accesses via jQuery autocomplete plugin as a drop down list. Should I data cache this list which will not change very often, or will I not gain much of a performance benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Why not measure both approaches and then make a decision based on actual data, rather than guesses?

Comment: How you suggest to measure it?

Comment: 1. Implement both options. 2. Implement a load testing script to generate requests and 3. measure how many requests per second, server load, etc

Answer (score 1):

Cache unless you got trouble.

try to cache both in server side, and in client side.

on the client side since you said that you using jquery, I know there is a auto-complete jquery plugins that can do it for you.

client side is good to only one page, so if you can do also server side.